# postgis loader osm shapefile

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I downloaded the map of my city already in shapefile into postgis http://metro.teczno.com/ to load in order to consult routes using pgRouting.

Iss happening the error: http://metro.teczno.com/

```
Importing with configuration: port-alegre.osm online, public, geom, C: \ Cassia \ Shape POA-OSM \ port-alegre.osm-line, mode = c, dump = 1, simple = 0, geography = 0, index = 1, shape = 1, srid = 4326 
C: \ Cassia \ Shape POA-OSM \ port-alegre.osm online: DBF file (. Dbf) can not be opened. 
Shapefile import failed.
```

I do not know what the geometry column in esquecificar postgisloader, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use https://mapzen.com/metro-extracts/ for more up to date data.

Second, you seem to be loading a raw osm file, and not a shapefile. Please try the same with "osm2pgsql shp" or "imposm shp" file for your region.